# YouTube API direct video/audio URLs

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I've read the documentation about the YouTube API (v3) and didn't find anything to only get the URL to the a video itself.

Is there a way to get **only** the video URL? If not, what's the purpose of this API?

There are a few apps on the AppStore(s) which use YouTube and they are able to stream videos from YouTube - are they using an unofficial API?

Comment: YouTube doesn't allow users of its API to access the video URL directly (e.g. the link to the .3gp/.mp4 file). You have to access the video through a videoId or whatever link the API returns and then display it in a web browser.

Comment: There are extension for Firefox, Chrome, Safari etc. which give you the exact URL to the video - is this allowed?

Comment: You are *able* to get the video URL, but you can't use it in any useful way in an app without breaking their terms of service. 
See section II-10 in https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=en

Comment: OK, damn. But thank you!